# Sum of all elements that are equal in a list with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say that I have this list:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

I want to be able to sum all the items that are equal in the list, so, sum 1s only with 1s, 2 only with 2s, etc. to produce an output like this:

```
[2,4,6,8]
```

This is on over simplification, the actual use case is that I have a list of objects, the object has defined the `__eq__`, `__add__` and `__radd__` methods so they can be added together and compared, but I'm just looking for a clean way to add the objects in the list only to others that are equal to it. I know I can use some sort of for loops to achieve this, but my attempts end up in long and un-readeable code. Can this be done with a list comprehension 1 liner?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the `__hash__` method to your class? That will allow you to put them in a dictionary or set to track all the equal elements.

Comment: Without that you'll need to put them in a list and do a search for each item to find the equal ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
[k*v for k,v in Counter(my_list).items()]
```

---

You can implement `__hash__` to make your hashable objects.

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.val)
```

From [*docs*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> If a class does not define an `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either; if it defines `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable as items in hashable collections. If a class defines mutable objects and implements an `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since the implementation of hashable collections requires that a key’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).

Comment: I believe `Counter` also needs `__hash__`

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Yes, keys need to be hashable objects.

Comment: OP is dealing with custom objects, so it might be good to clarify that `__hash__` needs to be defined.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Added it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

>>> result = [num*my_list.count(num) for num in set(my_list)]

>>> result
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

If you need a one-liner, as this answer itself is, it would save a lot of pain if you could define a `__hash__` in your function, as mentioned by others.

Comment: `set()` requires the list elements to be hashable.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with list comprehension:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
resp = [sum([_ for _ in my_list if _ == val]) for val in set(my_list)]
print(resp)
```

result:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: `set` requires that the elements be hashable.

Comment: @Barmar, you are correct. We don't have much info on the implementation of the objects. If they are not hashable, OP would need to create a list of unique objects first.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
my_list = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
result = [sum(b) for _, b in groupby(sorted(my_list))]
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like that:

```
from itertools import groupby
[sum(l) for v,l in groupby(sorted(my_list))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What kind of data would you sum that would not be comparable?

Comment: Complex numbers could be one example. I think your answer as valid as the rest, but we cannot say if it will work without more details from the OP.